# angular2 - set interval to check jwt token validity

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, intervals

I'm trying to create a standalone service that is only responsible for checking whether a token is expired or not.

Normally I would just start an Interval and test the JWT token using `tokenNotExpired()` or `JwtHelper.isTokenExpired()`. But with Angular2 I'm not so sure as how I'm I supposed to handle this kind of stuff. It can't be that easy, right? :)

All the token validity is currently being performed in home.component, but that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid and hence intend to separate this concern into a standalone service.

The below is just an hypothetical example as how it might be working.

- user logs-in
- home component initializes
- subscribe to session-check.service.validate()
- check the output of the session validation check

The problem here is, should I use Observable or just start a simple Interval? What's the best and most proper concept to handle periodical calls inside a component?

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { SessionCheckService } from '../services/session-check.service';


@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: '../templates/home.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ '../styles/home.component.css' ],
  providers: [ SessionCheckService ]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  private jwt: string;
  private decodedJwt: string;

  constructor (
    private router: Router, 
    private http: Http
    private sessionCheckService: SessionCheckService
   // private jwtHelper: JwtHelper
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.jwt = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
    // this.decodedJwt = null; //this.jwt && this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(this.jwt);
    var s = this.sessionCheckService.validate( this.jwt );
    s.subscribe((res) => {
        console.log( res )
    })
  }

  public logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
  }
}
```

**session-check.service.ts**

```
import { JwtHelper } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
//import { AuthHttp, JwtHelper } from 'angular2-jwt';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class SessionCheckService {
    constructor( private jwtH:  JwtHelper ){};

    validate( token:string ): Observable< boolean >{
        return new Observable.interval(500).flatMap( () => {
            this.jwtH.isTokenExpired( token )
        } );
    }
}
```

Comment: please have a look :angular2-jwt (https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt)

Comment: I already do check the token whenever a user tries opening the `/home` route. But my intention is to check the token periodically throughout it's lifetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it turned the returned value from `this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired( token )` wasn't correctly mapped. See below solution.

**session-check.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class SessionCheckService {
    constructor( private jwtHelper: JwtHelper ){};

    public validate( token:string ): Observable< any > {
        return Observable.interval(1000).map( (x) => this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired( token ) );
    }
}
```

Still I would like to know if this is a reasonable way to handle token expiration and eventually triggering logout procedure.

Answer (score 0):

add this line to `app.module.ts` cause services are `singleton` and this line will create multiple instances of service.

```
providers: [ SessionCheckService ]
```

Comment: apologies for not being clear enough, it's not that the service isn't reachable ...it's just I'm looking for an actual concept of how I should handle intervals inside the `home.component` and what should be used in the service for intervals.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a helper service for your request headers or an interceptor. so before you set the headers, you check if the token is still valid. if it isn't, you either refresh or redirect the user to login. this way, at every request, there is an automatic check if the token is still valid